# Can't see Spring MVC Project Template in STS 4

Tags: eclipse

I have just download Spring sts-4.3.0.RELEASE.
When I try to create new MVC project. I don't see any template to create MVC project. All I see Spring Boot folder and two templates to create a boot project. 
Please can someone help me what I have done wrong with STS setup.
I also update sts.
Is something changed with this new STS IDE.

thank you.
Ish